# Which React lifecycle method can I use `this` in before the render function is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was previously catching an error in my code using the component will mount method which is now being depreciated this was my code prevoiusly:

```js
   componentWillMount() {
   if (!this.context) {
        throw new Error('Error');
   }
}
```

- I considered adding my code to the `constructor` but that would not work since i cant use `this.` in the constructor
- I also considered considered other lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount` but this is called after the render function

what would be the best way to solve this issue? would it be bad practice to add my error catching code in the render function?

Comment: *"I considered adding my code to the constructor but that would not work since i cant use `this`. in the constructor"* Yes, you can; it's incredibly common to do that and it's [what the documentation says to do](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). Just do so after `super(props);`.

Comment: but the context of `this` is not coming from my props

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by that. I'm just saying that you can use `this` in your constructor. You can't use it before you call `super` (because it isn't set up yet until the base constructor of the class tree runs), but you can use `this` *after* calling `super`, and that's perfectly normal. So basically: `constructor(props) { super(props); if (!this.context) { throw new Error("Must have context"); } }`

Comment: I've posted the above as an answer, but if you prefer to remove the question, please feel free. (If someone upvotes my answer I'll have to delete it before you can delete the question; just ping me if you want to do that.) Happy coding!

Comment: I believe you may have some confusion around `this` in this context.  `this` will refer to the component instance in all react lifecycle methods, as well as in any class instance methods that are bound to `this` in the constructor.  `props` are a property of the class instance, and thus are accessible as `this.props`.

Comment: thanks that worked, sorry i thought you were saying i should use props like `props.context` just didnt read properly

Comment: @Adam - No worries and glad that helped!! Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I considered adding my code to the constructor but that would not work since i cant use `this`. in the constructor"

Yes, you can; it's incredibly common and it's [what the documentation says to do](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). Just do so after `super(props);`. (It has to be after you call `super` because it isn't set up yet until the base constructor of the class tree runs.)

So:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
    static contextType = YourContext;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Okay to use `this` now
        if (!this.context) {
            throw new Error("Must have non-falsy context");
        }
    }
    render() {
        return /*...*/;
    }
}
```

Or switch to a functonal component using hooks:

```
function YourComponent() {
    const [context] = useContext(YourContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("Must have non-falsy context");
    }
    return /*...*/;
}
```